# issue with autocomplete event with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using autocomplete event using a keyboard keypress event in the input

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = ["Amsterdam, Netherlands"];

  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }

  $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function(request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
          availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(", ");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="server_locations" class="form-control" placeholder="city" id="tags">
```

I am using this code to set autocomplete city name in my project

but when I use this code I have received

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined

I don't know why is this happening.

can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet is not working !

I copied and changed to `jquery ui 1.12.1`.

it's working!
If you require any further information, feel free to comment.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = ["Amsterdam, Netherlands"];

  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }

  $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function(request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
          availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(", ");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="server_locations" class="form-control" placeholder="city" id="tags">
```